# java7 jxtreetable not updating rows

Tags: java, swing

I have JXTreeTable and adding rows dynamically. The newly added rows are properly updated in JXTreeTable in java6. But in java7 newly added rows are not visible in UI. But I can see the treenodesInserted event triggered properly. I am calling updateUI method to reflect changes in UI. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us  some codes

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).